# Algorithmic and hyperref packages: strange interaction

Tags: hyperref, algorithmic

I am not sure the bug below has already been reported as I cannot find clear information online. See the MWE: if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is not commented, the space below the equation is fairly large, way more than when the package is commented. It looks like it is a bad interaction between `hyperref` and the `STATE` command of the `algorithmic` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
\STATE text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\STATE text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{algorithmic}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A solution by adding:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\vskip-0.5\baselineskip}

Comment: @M.Ahmadi Not sure because it affects all equations in the document and only very few of them have an issue.

Comment: usepackage algorithmicx  greatly improved algorithmic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

to

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
```

OR

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

And `\STATE` to `\State`
 does not create an empty space

The Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithmicx} 
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
\State text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\State text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{algorithmic}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Interesting. Then this is a bug to be reported to the algorithmic package maintainer.